# Absolute paths in build.gradle on Windows

Tags: gradle

- I defined an absolute path in `gradle.properties` to a keystore
- I am using Windows
- I have an empty space in the path

  RELEASE_STORE_FILE="D:\My Folder\Android\android.javakeystore.keystore.jks"

I receive the error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileNormaliser.normalise(FileNormaliser.java:54)
    ... 222 more
```

How do I define absolute paths on Windows in Gradle correctly?

Comment: have you tried double backslash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is coming from the surrounding " character in your property value from *gradle.properties* file. You should configure your property in *gradle.properties* as follows:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=D:\\My Folder\\Android\\android.javakeystore.keystore.jks
```

or

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=D:/My Folder/Android/android.javakeystore.keystore.jks
```

Gradle preserves the " character from properties value, so if you try something like that:

```
file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE).exits() // if RELEASE_STORE_FILE contains " char, it will fail
```

Other examples to illustrate this:

gradle.properties

```
cert_path_1=c:/my certs/cert.txt
cert_path_2="c:/my certs/cert.txt"
cert_path_3="c:\\my certs\\cert.txt"
cert_path_4=c:\\my certs\\cert.txt
```

build.gradle

```
void testFile(String message, String fileToTest){
    println message
    println " -> does the file exist? : " + file(fileToTest).exists() + "\n"
}

testFile("Testing property 'cert_path_1'", ext.cert_path_1)
testFile("Testing property 'cert_path_2'", ext.cert_path_2)
testFile("Testing property 'cert_path_3'", ext.cert_path_3)
testFile("Testing property 'cert_path_4'", ext.cert_path_4)
```

Result:

```
Testing property 'cert_path_1'
 -> does the file exist? : true

Testing property 'cert_path_2'
 -> does the file exist? : false

Testing property 'cert_path_3'
 -> does the file exist? : false

Testing property 'cert_path_4'
 -> does the file exist? : true
```